# The meaning of "in the worst sense of the word"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Mark Twain is said to have described a certain person as a good man **in the worst sense of the word**.

It's idiomatic(i think), what's it's true meaning?

Comment: It's an oxymoron referring to the people who use religion, law, custom, norms and social opinion to perpetuate racism, slavery, cruelty, injustice and even murder.

Comment: **compare**: in the best sense of the word. Mark Twain was being ironic for hits times.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of the phrase "Evil prospers when good men do nothing." which is not an accurate quote and is not from Mark Twain, but perhaps in the same vein. A good man does not offend anyone but fails to correct anything wrong. Not really a good man.